# Java Stream .map ternary operator

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a TXT.File with Lines which are representing some Objects

> R-Line (one)
>
> RN-Line (1...many)

they are connected with id so in order to read the file I made a `lines().stream`

```
Stream<Boolean> inLines = in.lines()
         //limit lines due to memory footprint
        .limit(10)
         //filter each line by the given id
        .filter(identN -> ident.matches(".*\\t[5]\\t.*"))
        /**
         * should return all lines with id 5
         * if line starts with RN put it in rnArray else in rArray so the objects are connected but i need for validation purposes each line seperate??
         */
        .map(y -> (y.startsWith("RN") ? synonym1.add(y) : substance.add(y)));
         

System.out.println("syn1 = " + synonym1.toString() + "substance: = " + substance + " InLines"+ inLines);
```

Response is empty :

```
syn1 = []substance: = [] InLinesjava.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@3aa9e816
```

But it doesn't work. The return of the .map should be another stream so how can I incorporate this logic if I use for each it won't work since I need also the r-Line.

Answer (score 1):

#### Cause

The response is empty since there is *no terminal operation* invoked on the `Stream` that you've created(`inLines`). Hence both  `synonym1` and `substance` remain empty while you try to access them while printing to the console.

#### Alternate

What you might just be looking for is to replace the final `map` operation with a `forEach`, since it would persist both `synonym1` and `substance` types of elements found which seems to be your primary use case. This can be done as:

```
.forEach(y -> {
    if (y.startsWith("RN")) {
        synonym1.add(y);
    } else {
        substance.add(y);
    }
});
```

#### Note

Currently, it doesn't make much sense to collect the `Stream<Boolean>` into a `Collection`, since that would include the result of `.add` operation on the `synonym1` and `substance` collections for each filtered element.

Comment: Ok thank what you mean by Terminal Operation also the ternary can‘t be used ? Why?

Comment: @MicroLova To understand what terminal operations mean refer to the [documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). And ternary operations shall be used, but only if their return values are required in the future operations.

Comment: ok from my understanding ternary is returning values and if/else is just a block returning nothing . Thanks got it very helpfull

Comment: ByNote: you mean if i would use the collect()-Method then that would include synonym1 and substance.adds to the Collectors.toList collection?

Comment: @MicroLova The `add` method has a `Boolean` return type for a successful addition to the collection. I meant the list would then have boolean values corresponding to the `add` operation if you collect it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Naman, it helped me alot since i found a way that allows me too use the ternary operator and split the stream into 2 seperate Lists by grouping the

```
 .forEach((x) -> ((x.startsWith("RN"))?synonym:substance).add(x));
```

so the problem is that the x operator was not in brackets i think it is because 
 grouping objects or is there any other explaination

Thanks